# VueJS: Use Vuex watcher to redraw/reflow a component

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

I have trouble accessing the Vue component. It is a chart which uses computed properties, which are reactive.

In the documentation I found an example how to "reflow" a the chart, which works fine. However I want to trigger this behaviour whenever the state changes.

```
  mounted() {
    this.isMounted = true;
    this.$store.watch(state => {
      if (state.lineData.data.length > 0) {
        this.reflow(); // ### Want to access the reflow method here 
// this.$computed.chartOptions.chart   desired something like this
      }
    });
  },
  computed: {
    chartOptions() {
      var ref = this;

      return {
        chart: {
          map: worldMap,
          height: "620px",
          events: {
            click: function() {
              console.log(this);
              this.reflow(); ### This works
            }
          }
        },

      }
    }
```

Is there a way to access the computed property from the `mounted` method or am I doing here something fundamentally wrong? Is there a better way to do this? The `click` event from the highcharts API is reserved and does not allow me to use custom methods :-/

Answer (score 0):

I found a (for me) good solution:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts"; // access to all highcharts components

Highcharts.charts[0].reflow(); // select the correct one an reflow it
```